# Receiving segmentation fault in C++ code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sfml

I'm using C++, code::blocks (with warnings enabled and I checked to make sure) and SFML.

I've tried hunting the bug down myself but I really can't find what's wrong. I know what a segfault means but this one really has me stumped. I'm a beginner may I add but am quickly learning.

I've got a basic main class `void Engine` that has a method `void RenderFrame` that renders every frame of the application. Inside said method I have this code which is supposed to draw all the tiles onto the renderwindow:

```
Tile* tile;    
for (short y = 0; y < mapHeight; ++y) {
    for (short x = 0; x < mapWidth; ++x) {
        tile    = currentLevel -> GetTile(x, y);

        if (tile) {
            tile -> Draw((x * tileSize), (y * tileSize), Wnd);
        }
    }
}
```

The GetTile method is supposed to return a tile from within a `std::vector<std::vector<Tile *> >`

The Draw method only does this:

```
void Tile::Draw(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow *pWnd) {
    sprite.SetPosition(x, y);
    pWnd -> Draw(sprite);
}
```

The application compiles just fine, but it crashes right after calling `sprite.SetPosition(x, y);`

This is the full call stack from the debugger:

```
#0 68701829 sf::Drawable::SetPosition(float, float) () (D:\Coding\C++\sfml\bin\debug\sfml-graphics.dll:??)
#1 004021F9 Tile::Draw(this=0x76ab8cd5, x=0, y=0, pWnd=0x3e3310) (D:\Coding\C++\sfml\include\Tile.cpp:12)
#2 00401D7E Engine::RenderFrame(this=0x3e3298) (D:\Coding\C++\sfml\include\Engine.cpp:106)
#3 00401B29 Engine::MainLoop(this=0x3e3298) (D:\Coding\C++\sfml\include\Engine.cpp:63)
#4 00401E27 _fu0___ZTIPKc(this=0x3e3298) (D:\Coding\C++\sfml\include\Engine.cpp:119)
#5 004022D6 main() (D:\Coding\C++\sfml\Main.cpp:8)
```

I hope this is enough information to go on, and thanks in advance.

Edit: Oh, and this is from the debugger output. `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In sf::Drawable::SetPosition(float, float) ()`
Doesn't give much more information about the problem.

Comment: Do you have the code of `sf::Drawable::SetPosition`? What is the definition of the `sprite`? Does the debugger not let you see the specific line in the function where it crashes?

Comment: Just curious: is sprite a Sprite or a Sprite&? If it's the second, is there any possibility that you did something like `sprite = *((Sprite*)NULL);` accidentally?

Comment: Is the sprite bigger than tilesize (even by 1 pixel)?

Comment: That stacktrace doesn't seem to match the code?  For example why is there a reference to `cout` before the call to `SetPosition` but no reference to the `Tile::Draw` method you show as the code.

Comment: David: sf::* is from the SFML library, I don't have any code from it. Luiscubal: The sprite is sf::Sprite sprite; Marty: tileSize is 32 and the sprite isn't any bigger. Trojanfoe: Oh woops, I had left in a cout for some quick testing but removed it in the code. Updating stack trace in a sec.

Comment: Could you reduce the problem and post a complete program that reproduces the problem?  It will be hard to diagnose with such little information.

Comment: Most likely explanation is that `sprite` is invalid for some reason -- its been corrupted or is a dangling reference or is somehow wrong.  Looking at the internals of sf::Drawable::SetPosition might tell you.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: ... or the `this` pointer in `Tile::Draw` is invalid (simpler explanation), maybe the pointers in the vector were not all properly initialized, or maybe the object was deleted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in the backtrace looks suspicious:

```
#1 004021F9 Tile::Draw(this=0x76ab8cd5, x=0, y=0, pWnd=0x3e3310)
```

This seems to correspond to your Tile::Draw function, except the `this` pointer is misaligned, which suggests that it's not a valid pointer.  So perhaps your `std::vector<std::vector<Tile *> >` has been corrupted somehow.

Comment: D'oh! I hadn't created a default tile for the cells in the `std::vector<std::vector<Tile *> >` so they were... Empty. Fixed it by looping over it creating an empty tile for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable explanation is that the pointer returned by `currentLevel->GetTile(x,y)` is not valid. This could be because it was not properly initialized (to either NUL or a valid allocated object) or because the object to which it refers has been destroyed. Both would explain that `sprite` is not a valid object and calling `SetPosition` on that object will pass an invalid `this` pointer that would trigger the SIGSEGV.

Comment: There is a check for a null pointer following this assignment.  However, a pointer may not be null, but still be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

A general cause of segmentation faults is dereferencing a null or invalid pointer.
 1. Check GetTile(), is this causing the fault?
 2. Check `currentLevel` before dereferencing.